# why can't I use parent method? (ArrayList)

Tags: java

everybody

I have some questions~

In the main method , `int size = s.getSize()`

but when I change to `int size = s.size()`

Why compiler show NoSuchMethodError?

Mystack is a ArrayList's child class

Why can't I use `size()` method?

```
package ch11;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ch11_10  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        MyStack s = getStack(input);

        int size = s.getSize();//換成s.size()


        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          System.out.println(s.pop());
        }
      }

      public static MyStack getStack(Scanner input) {
        System.out.print("Enter five strings: ");
        MyStack s = new MyStack();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          s.push(input.next());
        }
        return s;
      }
    }


class MyStack extends ArrayList {

  public int getSize() {
    return size();
  }

  public Object peek() {
    return get(size() - 1);
  }

  public Object pop() {
    Object o = get(size() - 1);
    remove(size() - 1);
    return o;
  }

  public void push(Object o) {
    add(o);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "stack: " + toString();
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add @Override to it, see if that part compiles. If not, you did not override it. Please share the full code, including any imports. See [mcve].

Comment: The code you posted passes compilation with `int size = s.size();`

Comment: I pasted your code and added the two missing imports, as well as a call to s.size(), and it compiles fine, as expected.

Comment: I assume the import could be wrong. Make sure it is java.util.ArrayList

Comment: It is not possbile that this is the full code. It must have an import declaration for the ArrayList. Or it is a custom class of yours in the same package.

Comment: hi i have import 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the full code you are using. And the full error message. As you see, your code works for us. So if you do not share the full details, your question will likely get closed as nobody can reproduce your issue.

Comment: sorry i try it 
i first use stackoverflow

Comment: i done it ~~ sorry everybody~~

Comment: @Zabuza i paste link in my post that's my question thx

Comment: Is this the only error you got? Does your code even compile? Are you sure you are not "force running" it? (trying to run code that does not even compile, some IDEs support this and run the latest code that compiled then, so old code). What happens if you remove the chinese comment, maybe an encoding issue?

Comment: **Warning**: You are extending the raw type `ArrayList`. **Never** do that.

Comment: My question is why can't I use s.size()?  s is a Mystack's object ,and MyStack extends ArrayList class ...  When I type int size = s.getSize(); It works. but change to int size = s.size()? why shows NoSuchMethodError?

Comment: We know what your question is, you stated that already. But you can use it, the code you provide works on our end. So there must be something different leading to this issue, which is why we ask you those questions. So please work towards answering those, else we can not really do anything. So again, if I just copy paste your code, it works on my end, no issues. I just needed to either remove the chinese comment or change the encoding of the file to UTF-8. Which is why I asked you to do that.

Comment: hey guys , I use mac but when i use my code in windows. It works!!! why????

Comment: @chiwen I use a Mac and your posted code works fine.  It's nothing to do with your code but more likely how it's been built